# how can I extract multiple gzip files in directory and subdirectories?

Tags: gzip

I have tried both `gzip` and `gunzip` commands but I get either

```
gunzip *.gz 
gzip: invalid option -- 'Y' 

gunzip -S-1800-01-01-000000-g01.h5.gz  
gzip: compressed data not read
 from a terminal. Use -f to force decompression. For help, type: gzip -h
```

If I try the `-f` option it takes a very long time to work on one single file and the command is not executed successfully. Am I missing something?

Comment: Does the directory contain .gz files whose names start with hyphens, such as `-Y.something.gz`? If so you may need to use the Gnu `--` flag to ensure that they are treated as filenames rather than options i.e. `gunzip -- *.gz`

Comment: @steeldriver yes I do have a few files starting with -

Comment: that caused at least one of the two problems.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can use below command.

Go to the directory where your `.gz` file is and run command:

```
for f in *.gz ; do gunzip -c "$f" > /home/$USER/"${f%.*}" ; done
```

It will extract all file with original name and store it to current user home directory(`/home/username`). You can change it to somewhere else.

**EDIT :**

```
gunzip *.gz
```

This command also will work. But, by default, it replaces original file.

Comment: Have you read what I wrote in my question? gunzip *.gz is not working for me. But the for loop works, I am puzzled.

Comment: but it is working for me and others also  why is showing ` invalid option -- 'Y'  ` . i think either your file format is not ok or you missing some thing in command.

Comment: also see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56421/gunzip-all-gz-files-in-directory

Answer (score 14):

**Option # 1** : unzip multiple files using single quote (short version)

```
gunzip '*.gz'
```

Note that `*.gz` word is put in between two single quote, so that shell will not recognize it as a wild card character.

**Option # 2** : unzip multiple files using shell for loop (long version)

```
for g in *.gz; do gunzip $g; done
```

[The Source](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-shell-unzipping-many-zip-files/)

**EDIT :**

I have just tried :

```
gunzip -dk *.gz
```

and it worked.

`-d` to decompress and `k` to keep original files.

Comment: have you checked `gunzip ‘*.gz’ ` this command . i  am not able to run this command .  it giving error .

Comment: use `gunzip '*.gz'` not `gunzip ‘*.gz’ ` (`' '` not `‘  ``)

Comment: i am just copy pasting your command and it giving `gzip: *.gz: No such file or directory` new also not working . have u tried ?

Comment: It does not work gunzip '*.gz'
gzip: *.gz: No such file or directory

Comment: Sorry, i didn'ttry it ! i'm on WIndows Right now :(

Answer (score 6):

Linux Users:

Use the following command for extracting minimum amount of .gz files in the current directory and its sub directories

```
gunzip *.gz
```

Use the following command for extracting any number of .gz files in the current directory and its sub directories

```
sudo find . -name "*.gz" | xargs gunzip
```

Comment: how to understand "minimum amount of .gz files"? as "0 or 1"?

Comment: Why are you using `sudo`?