# bash : make a new dir and get files inside gzs and tars

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, files

I have a bunch of tared and gz files. I saw [how can I extract multiple gzip files in directory and subdirectories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/693409/how-can-i-extract-multiple-gzip-files-in-directory-and-subdirectories%20gzip%20in%20dir%20and%20sub%20directories) i want something similar but first a new sub directory for each tar file.

All the archives are in one directory (say /u/z1/ with no sub directories in the beginning):
1.tar.gz
2.tar.gz

but they have similar files in the tars, say 1.txt, 2.txt

I do not want them over written.

So in generic bash script, want to iterate over all the files, make a sub directory with the same name as the file (/u/z1/gzs/1.tar.gz or 1.tar or just 1 is fine).

Then extract only the cuurent gz file to this new sub directory (cd to it?), then make a new directory 1.tar, under /u/z1/tars/ and untar the files to that directory.

Finally move to the next file and repeat. In the end we have directories: /u/z1/tars/1/, /u/z1/tars/2/, /u/z1/tars/3/ etc with respective files of that tar.

Comment: Actually, `gzip`ped files don't have files "inside them". If you compress a file with `gzip`, the resulting file doesn't know anything about the original file name. Are you maybe talking about compressed `tar` archives (`.tgz` or `.tar.gz`)?

Comment: Yes you right @philippos